# Python extracting number from HTML tag using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

I am working on a web scraper using beautiful soup. Here is my function:

```
    journalist_result = soup.find_all("h4",class_="slab")
    if len(journalist_result)>0:
        journalist_share = int(re.match(r'\d+', journalist_result[0].get_text()).group())
    else:
        journalist_share=0
```

Basically, what I want to do is to extract the number of journalist that shared a link. In this case is 221 (see below for example):

CASE1:

```
<h4 class="slab">221 journalists shared this link.
      <a href="/pros">Join</a> or <a href="/account/login?next=/whosharedmylink/?url=http://www.cnn.com/">sign in</a> to Muck Rack to view their names.</h3>
```

My code works fine for cases where there are journalist shares or if an URL is not found.
However, my code breaks on the following case:

CASE2:

```
<h4 class="slab" style="margin-bottom:5px">

      This link hasn't yet been shared by any journalists.<br /><a href="/pros">Learn about using Muck Rack Pro</a> to connect with journalists.
</h4>
```

this is because in case 2, there are no journalist found. And the error I am getting is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "muckrackscraper.py", line 65, in 
    journalist_share = int(re.match(r'\d+', journalist_result[0].get_text()).group())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

THanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you've misunderstood why your code is failing. It's *not* in case 2, but in case 1 where you don't check the return value from `re.match` and then attempt a function call on `None`.

From the [re.match documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match):

> Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note that this
>   is different from a zero-length match.

So your pattern is not matching whatever is in `journalist_result[0].get_text()`; try inspecting this value and also add a check for `None`.